# Animating/rotating a spherical emitter object without rotating the child hair objects

Tags: animation, hair

I have a simple test animation here where I create a simple 26 vert roundcube, add a particle system, emit from verts, and use a pyramid object as the render object using object rotation and scale. Animating movement or scale of the emitter works exactly as I'd want. Rotation, however, around Z in this test example, rotates the child objects as well in different ways (top don't rotate with emitter, middle flip their orientation when they reach the x axis, those at 45 degrees smoothly rotate). How do I get them to just stick to the emitter surface while it rotates?

[image: emitter rotation test]

Edit in response to the question below: Here's an isolated test file with the animation in question. The pyramid has a side colored so the rotation is easier to see. https://pasteall.org/blend/08e6a72225284573834722ed482adfe7

Update... to see where this was originally headed, this is where I was in trying to model this animation from Arcane as a practice exercise. I'll still want the effect from the graph editor/noise modifier as the pyramids bounce in and out a bit: [image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here's an isolated test file with the animation in question. The pyramid has a side colored so the rotation is easier to see. https://pasteall.org/blend/08e6a72225284573834722ed482adfe7

Comment: Have you tried child [instancing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html) instead?  It seems to work a little more predictably than particle systems.

Comment: I have and there's a different set of problems there and it's potentially more difficult to animate. I need them to expand outward a bit (scale the emitter, with a noise modifier) and making the objects real and scaling/rotating as a group or parenting to an empty causes issues with either scale affecting the scale of the children or (if doing something transform>affect only>locations) the scale works but rotation then rotates the children.

Comment: for me this looks like a bug...

Comment: did you ever try geometry nodes? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ8Ny.gif left is your particle system, right geometry nodes

Comment: It looks like geometry nodes is going to be the best answer. I'll get back to the project this weekend and will update. Appreciate the ideas.

Comment: Just getting back to this. I'm new to geometry nodes and am having trouble replicating what you did. Looks like you may have "applied" the particle system between these steps? Not sure if that works since I'd like individual control still to add some jitter of the individual pyramids. Playing with scale in the nodes doesn't do what I want there however (I added more reference images to the above post). Also, did you keyframe and transform "value" on the timeline or do something else to animate it like tie the value to a multiple of "frame"?

Comment: Make a new post for geometry nodes. For this question, this is obviously the default behaviour for particles, you can get around it, by simulating your object statically (without rotation), put it in a collection, then instance that collection and animate the rotation using the collection.

Comment: @ Leander, so maybe you should give this trick as an answer?